# 2 Parameter Margules derivation

Tags: chemical-engineering, vapor-pressure

I'm trying to find online the derivation for the 2 parameter margules equation but cant find it anywhere.

basically need to prove
$$
\frac{d}{dn1} (x_{1}x_{2}(A_{21}x_{1} + A_{12}x_{2})) = x_2^2(A_{12} + 2(A_{21}-A_{12})x_{1})
$$

but everytime I try just end up with a page full of rubbish. I've searched online for the derivation but cant find it anywhere.

EDIT: the A values are functions of temperature only and can be considered constants

Comment: @J.Ari is it not the model itself x1x2(Ax1 + Bx2) that is a power series fit? the activity coefficient equation can then be derived from that model using first principles

Comment: You're right, my first comment was mixing concepts so I deleted it. What I meant to say was the the 2 parameter excess Gibbs model is a curve fit and not formed from first principles, which is what I thought you were trying to find. The activity coefficients are found by differentiating the first term only while using the Gibbs-Duhem equation.

Comment: This question is a matter of going through the calculus rigorously, I don't think there is a trick you are missing.

Comment: You should rather post this question on https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/ or https://physics.stackexchange.com/. It is more likely that you will get a quick answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Hope this helps!]

Hope it makes a lil more sense. Be careful to multiply your excess gibbs by n & xlx2 from the activity coefficient relationship with gibbye! Also, be super grateful you didn't have to do the same thing for the Margules 3 parameter that I literally just worked out like 15 minutes before I saw this!

Comment: If possible, please [edit] your answer replacing the image with text and MathJax (allows proper math formatting such as $\ln\gamma_1 = 0$).